# Error while importing a Swagger JSON on WSO2 API Manager 2.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an existing API definition and when I try to import the same on the WSO2 API Manager (Version 2.1). I get an error, it states in an alert - Error occurred while importing swagger URL. (snapshot attached).

[API Publisher Error - Importing Swagger URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxSII.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the swagger definition above is valid, this might be a result of the size of the swagger file because I've seen some cases in the API-Manager publisher while uploading large swagger files. I was able to upload them through the jaggery API [1] of the API-Manager publisher successfully.

[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Publisher+APIs